# Different between index locations on tensors

Tags: metric-tensor, tensor-calculus, notation

My question is in regard to the position of upper and lower indices on tensors, specifically in this case I am considering position 4-vectors and the Minkowski matrix.

On the Wikipedia page I see the metric defined as both $ \eta_{\mu\nu} = \eta^{\mu\nu} $, however I feel like I have also seen rank-2 tensors in the form of $ \eta^{\mu}_{\nu} $ and I am having a hard time realizing why there is a difference.

So lets say for example I was looking at the inner product of the position 4-vector. This is what I would currently write based on my understanding.

$$
x^\mu x_\mu = x^\mu \eta^{\nu}_{\mu}x_{\nu}
$$

So with my way, I am writing the metric in a way that doesn't appear on the Wikipedia page. Perhaps my notation for the inner product is wrong? Should I instead be writing

$$
x^\mu x^\mu = x^\mu \eta^{\mu\nu}x_{\nu} \\
x_{\mu}x_\mu = x_\mu \eta_{\mu\nu}x^\nu
$$

as the inner product? I feel as though I have a basic understanding of what is going on, but I must be confused with some subtlety. Any help and explanation is appreciated!

Comment: Are you familiar with the difference between covariant and contravariant indices?